# Configuring config.assets.precompile to load admin styles appropriately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a web app and as part of the app, we have an admin panel. We're using Bootstrap for it and want the styles applied in production for just admin pages, we have other styles for the rest of the app.

Currently, admin styles aren't being loaded correctly in production. Hoping that some configuration of `config.assets.precompile` ought to do it.

In `application.css` I have:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require users
```

In `admin.css.scss` I have:

```
/*
  *= require_self
  *= require bootstrap
*/

body.admin {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

body.admin {

  table {
    td.actions {
      text-align: right;
    }
  }

  form {
    .form-actions {
      margin-top: 1em;
    }
  }

}
```

In `scaffolds.css.scss` I have a bunch of styles scoped to `body.admin`. And then there is a users SCSS file that isn't really relevant.

What's currently happening without a `config.assets.precompile` array set, the app loads fine, but the admin styles (bootstrap) aren't loading.

All of these files are nested in `/app/assets/stylesheets`.

Any help would be very appreciated. Deploying on Heroku, Cedar stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does precompiling before uploading help?

locally (shell) run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

in config/environments/production.rb set

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

then run in your shell

```
git add .
git commit -am 'precompiled assets'
git push heroku
```